# Convert varchar to datetime to sort date?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I want to try sorting dates but there are constraints, because those columns are varchar.

This existing data

[image]

This is the query that I test.

```
SELECT        PERIODE, RF, APPROVE_DATE
FROM            DLY_UPGRADE
WHERE        (SLP = '368') AND (CONVERT(datetime, APPROVE_DATE, 101) > '01/01/2017')
```

The error message :

[image]

Comment: why are you using varchar to store date in the first place ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, try the following:

```
SELECT        PERIODE, RF, APPROVE_DATE
FROM            DLY_UPGRADE
WHERE        (SLP = '368') AND (CONVERT(date, APPROVE_DATE, 103) > '2017-01-01')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`APPROVE_DATE`, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

To change date from string and then compare with `Y-m-d` format

```
 SELECT        PERIODE, RF, APPROVE_DATE
 FROM            DLY_UPGRADE
 WHERE        (SLP = '368') AND (DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`APPROVE_DATE`, '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')) > '2017-01-01')
```

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful with similar cases. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT        PERIODE, RF, APPROVE_DATE, cast(PERIODE as datetime) as PERIODEDatetime
FROM            DLY_UPGRADE
WHERE        (SLP = '368') AND (CONVERT(datetime, APPROVE_DATE, 101) > '01/01/2017')
order by PERIODEDatetime asc
```

Here you can cast your `varchar` to `datetime` and use that to order in asc/desc.
It's the same thing for APPROVE_DATE as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your conversion problem would *appear* to be in the `WHERE` clause.  But, before proceeding with the query, I would test using `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
select approve_date
from dly_upgrade
where slp = '368' and approve_date is not null and
      try_convert(date, approve_date, 103) is null;
```

The style `101` is MM/DD/YYYY, so `'15/11/2016'` is going to fail because `15` is not a valid month.  `103` is DD/MM/YYYY, which appears to be what you want.

Assuming that this returns no unexpected values in the column, I would suggest:

```
SELECT PERIODE, RF, APPROVE_DATE
FROM  DLY_UPGRADE
WHERE SLP = '368' AND
      TRY_CONVERT(datetime, APPROVE_DATE, 103) > '2017-01-01'
ORDER BY ?  -- not sure if you want PERIOD or TRY_CONVERT(datetime, APPROVE_DATE, 103)
```

Comment: Thanks my problem is done. I just need to adjust the date format 101 code with 01-01-2017